# iOS dialog message box like drop down list

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

[image]

Hi, I'm using objective-c sorry for image language i want to learn dialog box name. I researched but i could not found "Şifreni mi Unuttun ?" "Yardım Merkezi" "iptal" how can i display this box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a [`UIAlertController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/) with a `preferredStyle` property of `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet`.

There's a great tutorial for how to use `UIAlertController` in iOS 8 here: http://nshipster.com/uialertcontroller/.

Answer (score 1):

That is a UIActionSheet. Or in iOS 8 use a UIAlertController (it is better).